# How to define content popularity and trend

Tags: lists, taxonomy

I am trying to understand what is defined as "popular" and "trending" in websites that provide content. Some seem to list content that has more comments as being popular within a timeframe, but some seem to define popularity of content based on the number of views within a specific timeframe. Similarly with trending content, but this seems more towards content that has the most views within a timeframe with less focus on comments.

Is there a clear definition of what the user should be seeing when they click on a "popular" or "trending" menu selection?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think that there can be clear definitions for <kbd>Popular</kbd> or <kbd>Trending</kbd> (*who* should define it?!). I guess in many cases such algorithms are "secret" and take several characteristics into account.

But why not make it clear?

- <kbd>Most viewed</kbd>
- <kbd>Best rated</kbd>
- <kbd>Most commented</kbd>

If you also want to use several characteristics (e.g., an algorithm that uses the views count and the time after which the first *n* comments werde made), such clear labels won’t work, of course. So choose, for example, <kbd>Popular</kbd>, and if you like you can describe on the corresponding page how it gets decided which content is *popular*. I guess it depends on your users if they are interested in this at all (for many sites, a description of the algorithm is probably irrelevant).